# Too many columns on table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to upload csv data to sql in my django project.my csv data has 4000 date field which treated as a column.If i upload csv data it's shows me too many columns.In this case i used sqlite3 as a database.How to handle this.

Comment: Can you split the CSV files -- outside of the database -- into multiple files with no more than 1000 columns per file?

Comment: No.i can't split csv files into multiple files@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

Do your data fields use a comma? By default csv files determine a new column based on commas. If this is your issue, then one might define a specific delimiter character that is not present in any of your data fields (i.e. a pipe = | )

Comment: My data fields use a comma.my problem when i used too many column like 3000 or more. if i work 5 date columns to check it as a dummy. it works fine but  all date fields to needed as a column in my project .@Harley